# How do I convert my quarter note tempo into an eighth note tempo?

Tags: tempo

I made a song with a tempo of Quarter Note = 50, but I want to change the tempo to eighth notes. What would my new tempo be?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit to tell us a bit more about the situation. Do you mean that you have a tempo marking at the start of your piece that uses a quarter note and you want to switch to an eighth note? (In that case... 100.) Or do you maybe have a change in time signature in the middle of your piece, perhaps one with "8" as the bottom number, and you want to put a new tempo marking there? If so, do you want the *beat* to feel the same (in which case, eighth note = 50 still), or do you want eighth notes before the change to still equal eighth notes after the change (100)?

Answer (score 1):

The tempo specifies how many notes of that length fit into one minute. As an eighth note is half as long as a quarter you can fit twice as many eighth notes into a minute. So your tempo becomes eighth = 2·50 = 100